# C++ Primer 12.1:Can I implement StrBlob with a static vector<string> member inside class?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, static-members

In C++ Primer Section 12.1.1 (page 457) authors are trying to demonstrate a point that you can use shared_ptr to share data between several objects.

However, it sounds to me that the most straightforward way would be to simply define a static member inside class which is automatically shared among all objects. And we don't even need to bother using shared_ptr at all.
IMHO the textbook already has a solution in mind and tries to find a problem to this solution.

Any ideas on this and what's the best in practice in writing real code?

Comment: `static` is for sharing variables across *all* instances of the object, but what if you only want to share across several ones?

Comment: `static` variable will also live until the end of the program. The `shared_ptr` will be destroyed once the reference count hits zero (However the backing magic works). That said, `static` may be the right tool for the job. A more clear cut case is when you have different classes sharing the same `shared_ptr`. Say you have an object in a `vector` to maintain ordering and again in a `set` for high-speed look-up.

Comment: @user4581301 Global and static variables with class type are destroyed at some point during program execution, they don't live forever. An object really managed by a smart pointer (like `shared_ptr`) lives until the last owner goes: if a `shared_ptr` is kept around, it guarantees, in principle, that the controlled object is kept too.

Answer (score 0):

With `shared_ptr` it is possible to share data between a subset of objects of type `T`, a `static` member variable shares a single value across all instances of `T`. As you see the former is much more flexible.

An example would be the implementation of `shared_ptr` itself. The reference count is shared between all shared pointers pointing to the same object, pointers managing another object would have a separate shared reference count and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I didn't not realize `shared_ptr` does provide more flexibility on a more granular way of manipulation of the shared object.